# Обращение к методу класса к другому классу

Tags: javascript

Я не знаю как правильнее описать словами чего я хочу добиться, но могу показать кодом, что я хочу.
Я хочу обратиться к методу как-то вот так:

```js
const test = new Vk('...');
test.messages.getDialogs();
test.status.set('...');
```

Как такое можно провернуть? Делается ли это как-то так:

```js
class Vk
{
    constructor(token, version = 5.95)
    {
        this.token = token;
        this.version = version;

        this.messages = new VkMessages();
        this.status = new VkStatus();
    }
}

class VkMessages
{
    getDialogs()
    {
        /* тут должно использоваться this.token, this.version взятое из класса Vk */
    }
}

class VkStatus
{
    set()
    {
        /* тут должно использоваться this.token, this.version взятое из класса Vk */
    }
}
```

... или как-то иначе?

Comment: Непонятно зачем VkMessages наследуется от Vk и какое это всё имеет отношение к ВКонтакте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почти. Если выполните код, который вы написали, то получите ошибку о том, что превысили размер call stack. Почему так? Просто потому что конструктор Vk инициализирует VkMessages, а тот в свою очередь extend класс Vk. Таким образом, конструктор Vk выполняется вновь и вновь, пока есть место в call stack-е, а когда места больше нет, то появляется ошибка.

Но ведь VkMessages вовсе не нужно extend класс Vk, так ведь? Следовательно делаем крохотное изменение в вашем коде, и получаем работающий вариант:

```
class Vk
{
    constructor(token, version = 5.95)
    {
        this.token = token;
        this.version = version;

        this.messages = new VkMessages();
    }
}

class VkMessages // ← Вот тут изменение.
{
    getDialogs()
    {
        return [];
    }
}

const test = new Vk('');
test.messages.getDialogs();
```

Вот более полный пример, где `token` и `version` передвинуты в отдельный класс, который представляет из себя контекст программы, и передается от `Vk` к `VkMessages`.

```
class VkContext
{
    constructor(token, version = 5.95)
    {
        this.token = token;
        this.version = version;
    }
}

class Vk
{
    constructor(context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.messages = new VkMessages(context);
    }
}

class VkMessages
{
    constructor(context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    getDialogs()
    {
        return [];
    }
}

const context = new VkContext('');
const test = new Vk(context);
test.messages.getDialogs();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, в методах класса VkMessage будет использоваться свойства token и version из класса Vk, он их разве увидит?

Comment: @OliverPatterson При вызове передайте параметр `new VkMessages(this);` а в конструкторе VkMessages можно сохранить какую-нибудь ссылку `constructor(vk) { this.__vk__ = vk; }` тогда в getDialogs можно получить доступ через `this.__vk__.token`

Comment: @OliverPatterson: Если эти свойства—контекст, то для них можете создать свой собственный класс, например VkContext. Во всяком случае, система где по кругу конструктор одного класса вызывает конструктор другого работать не будет.

Comment: А как можно сделать, чтобы можно было просто this.token? В идеале должно получиться так, что я ицинизирую класс Vk и имею доступ к методам других классов, то есть это будет не только VkMessages. Допустим я захочу ```const test = new Vk('...'); test.messages.getDialogs(); test.status.set('...');``` Как такое реализовать? В методах классов VkMessages будет использованные данные из класса Vk, то есть token, version.

Comment: @OliverPatterson: Можно. В VkMessages, добавляете переменные `token` и `version`, а в конструкторе `Vk`, делаете так, что когда он создаёт новую инстанцию `VkMessages`, то даёт ей `token` и `version`. При этом советую вам подумать о создании класса контекста. Иначе замучаетесь каждый раз передавать и token, и version, и возможно другие переменные, которые добавятся в будущем.

Comment: Можете это как-то написать кодом, чтобы было более понятно? Спасибо.

Comment: @OliverPatterson: Сделано. См. измененный ответ.

Comment: ```const context = new Context('');``` тут ошибка допущена? нужно ```new VkContext```?

Comment: @OliverPatterson: Точно. Сорри.

Comment: Ничего страшного. Допустим. А что если я захочу изменить из Vk допустим токен? То есть ```test.setToken('new token')````. Этот способ же уже не подойдет?

Comment: @OliverPatterson: Почему же? Можете. Если в `Vk`, у вас есть метод `setToken(token)` который выполняет `this.context.token = token`, то это позволит менять значение токена, при этом и `VkMessages` будет читать новое значение.

Comment: А если нужно сделать функцию, которая будет использоваться в VkMessages, VkStatus, так сказать общую, ее нужно выносить получается в контекст? В данном случае функция, которая делает запросы.

Comment: @OliverPatterson: Смотря какая функция. Если речь о запросах HTTP, то нет: логичнее иметь отдельный класс (или серию классов) с такими методами, и уже их вызывать из Vk или VkMessages (давая им контекст по мере надобности). Дальше это уже рассуждения в плане дизайна кода, а с этим вам нужно идти на [SE.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) и объяснять более детально какой класс как и с кем общается.